# Renaming characters in multiple files in a folder

Tags: python, file, module, directory, rename

I'm trying to rename files in a folder with import os.
[Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIeHb.png)

I want to replace the 'SN' in all these files with 'NG'.

I have tried with the code
`

```
filenames = os.listdir(serial_dir) #serial_dir is the right path
for filename in filenames:
            dst = filename.replace('SN', 'NG')
            os.rename(filename, dst)
```

`
I have tested by printing out "filenames" and get the return:

```
['SN0000244,calibrationCheck1.txt', 'SN0000244,calibrationCheck2.txt', 'SN0000244,CurrentCalibration1.csv', 'SN0000244,CurrentCalibration2.csv', 'SN0000244,CurrentCalibrationFit1.csv', 'SN0000244,CurrentCalibrationFit2.csv', 'SN0000244.txt']
```

But i get the error: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Thanks.

I tried searching stackoverflow for answers but got nothing.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this script doesnt provide me with a specific line. It is a function within a much larger program. I only get this message saying 'can only concatenate str (not "int") to str'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.rename` looks for files in the current directory, not in the directory you specified. You should add the directory path before the file name.

```
serial_dir = 'path/to/dir'
filenames = os.listdir(serial_dir)
for filename in filenames:
    dst = filename.replace('SN', 'NG')
    os.rename(f'{serial_dir}/{filename}', f'{serial_dir}/{dst}')
```